# How can I detect if there is any file in a folder using SSIS?

Tags: c#, script-task, ssis-2017

I receive every day a file with a specific pattern and extension, which I want to run under certain process. I want to check if there is any file in my folder, because otherwise I will do another task. So far I found that you can use a Script Task and do a File.Exist. However, I'm doing something wrong because it doesn't take the * as a wildcard.
Devoluciones_source is "C:\Users\us1\Folder\"
FileToSearch is "return"

My files:
return_20200102.csv
return_20200203.csv

```
String Filepath = Dts.Variables["$Project::Devoluciones_source"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::FileToSearch"].Value.ToString() + "*csv";

        if (
            File.Exists(Filepath))

        {
            Dts.Variables["User::IsFound"].Value = 1;
        }
```

Comment: have you tried `*.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think File.Exits() accepts wildcards, it checks the literal filepath and will return false because `C:\Users\us1\Folder\*.csv` is not found.

What you could do instead is get the files in the folder `C:\Users\us1\Folder\` and checking those agains a searchPattern using `Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern)`

Like this:

```
string dirPath = Dts.Variables["$Project::Devoluciones_source"].Value.ToString(); 
string fileName = Dts.Variables["User::FileToSearch"].Value.ToString();

// if you want to make sure the directory exists:
if(Directory.Exists(dirPath) {
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, fileName + "*.csv");

    if(files.lenght > 0) {
        // you can now iterate over each file that is found in the users directory that matches your pattern and do your logic.
    }
}
```

Some more info on the Directory.GetFiles method: [Directory.GetFiles on docs.Microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_)

Some more info on the Files.Exists method: [Directory.GetFiles on docs.Microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netframework-4.8)